# Remove file location from document print using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to print a div contents it works fine but it also prints the file location on top-right position which gives an odd impression on the output. here i attached the snap of it.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: can i get get source code for this? and in Advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all specially zzzzBov From the menu in the top left corner of your browser, choose "File", then "Page setup..". Go to the second tab called "Margins & Header / Footer", in the drop down lists choose "Blank" for all the items you don't want printed. The screenshot below gives a better view of what I mean.
[image]

And for other browsers you can read the complete article on [enter link description here](http://www.mintprintables.com/print-tips/header-footer-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

This link has nothing to do with your code. It is put there by the browsers printing engine.

In most browsers, the *user* can change that, in others (e.g. Chrome) they can't.

Either way, there's nothing you can do from your end.

Comment: If it is , then how could I disable from FF and or IE?

Comment: As an example, to remove these extra bits of info in Firefox go to `Page Setup` -> `Margins & Header/Footer`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser controls this. There are no javascript functions to control this (and likely never will be due to potential for abuse)

Comment: If it is , then how could I disable from FF and or IE?